# Como criar uma variavel dinâmica

Tags: javascript, array, string, for

Tenho um campo(input text), e gostaria de pegar o `value`, e passar como variavel.

Em outras palavras, passar o valor deste campo texto para dentro da:

> **var** `valor do campo aqui` **;**

Vide o exemplo que deixo:

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
var nome
nome = window.prompt("Digite o nome para variável:");
document.write("var " +nome+ ";<br>");
//-->
</script>
```

> Este exemplo dá uma idéia clara. A real intenção é que, o resultado seja incluso em tempo de execução, no código fonte, setado como `variável` dentro da `function exemplo(){ var +nome+ = "valor"; };` e/ou `function exemplo(){ var valor = "+nome+" };`. Seria algo como um id(identificador) que receberia qualquer valor.

Tenho elaborado este exemplo mais concreto da seguinte forma:

```
<script language="javascript">
 <!--
  var nome 
  nome = window.prompt("Digite o nome:");
  variavel = document.createElement('script');
  variavel.textContent = nome; 
  document.getElementById("id").appendChild(variavel);
 //-->
</script>
```

> Mas, só consigo criar elementos HTML, nada funcional pro propósito, no qual preciso incorporar diretamente no código fonte da página aberta dentro do `script`.

Espero ter sido claro. Agradeço ajuda, desde ja.

Comment: Olá Diego. Está pouco clara a pergunta. Tens um `<input type="text">` correto? e depois queres que o valor inserido aí vá para uma variável certo? podes explicar melhor o que acontece depois?

Comment: Diego, dá um salto aqui: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25038/javascript

Comment: Juntei resposta em baixo, a ver se ajuda. Se tens problemas a aceder ao chat por causa do navegador faz download do Chrome ou Firefox e testa de novo.

Comment: Tem certeza que você precisa criar variáveis com o nome dinâmico assim e não bastaria usar campos de uma tabela global, como `var minhatabela = {};  minhatabela[nomedocampo] = valordocaompo`? Se você sair sobrescrevendo variáveis globais tem sempre a chance de estragar o valor de alguma variável existente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se percebi bem a tua pergunta queres criar um script, e pelo menos uma variável cujo nome é defenido por um `<input>` no HTML. Depois queres inserir esse script na página de modo a que dê para ver com as ferramentas do browser.

Acho que é isto que procuras:

```js
function addScript(varname) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerText = 'var ' + varname + ' = 10; alert(' + varname + ');';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

var input = document.querySelector('input');
var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
 var name = input.value;
 addScript(name);
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button>testar</button>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g4vfdsj1/

O que esse script faz é esperar que o `button` seja clicado, depois vai buscar o valor do input, depois chama uma função a quem passa esse valor do input, depois cria um elemento script e insere-lhe o valor do input e por fim insere-o no DOM.

Answer (score 4):

> O *método* `eval();` é uma opção.
>   Talvez a única resposta aqui que irá trabalhar para as variáveis ​​não-globais. Embora `eval();` não deve ser utilizado neste caso como existem métodos melhores.
>
> Falando em métodos melhores você pode usar o *objeto* `window` tem uma referência para todas as variáveis ​​globais e funções globais que você está usando.
>
> Mas, se você não quiser usar um *método* `eval();` ou *objeto* `window`. você pode tentar algo como isto:

```
<script language="javascript">
 <!--
 var obj = {}; 
 obj['teste'] = 'Não há mais necessidade de armazenar em um objeto global.\nO segredo fica por conta do acesso a propriedades via string.'; 
 alert(obj['teste']); 
 //-->
</script>
```

***Em JavaScript esses dois são equivalentes:***
`obj.teste = 'valorString'`
`obj['teste'] = 'valorString'`

> Para ilustrar um pouco melhor o funcionamento de algum destes *métodos/objetos*, criei exemplos que utiliza uns exemplos para demonstrar o uso das variáveis dinâmicas

**Exemplo 1**

```
<script language="javascript">
 <!--
 var nome;
 nome = window.prompt("Digite o nome:");
 var x = nome;
 var valor = 'x';
 // resultado
 alert(eval(valor)); 
 //-->
</script>
```

**Exemplo 2**

```
<script language="javascript">
 <!--
 var nome;
 nome = window.prompt("Digite o nome");
 var x = 'valor';
 str = x+' = '+'nome';
 eval(str);
 // resultado
 alert(valor);
 //-->
</script>
```

> Se você precisa criar ***variáveis dinâmica em Javascript***, e não sabe de quantas variáveis vai precisar. Use a *sintaxe* `for`, faça um *loop* com o *método* `eval();`. O *método* `eval();` recebe como parâmetro uma *String* que será executada como se fosse um comando. Veja:

**Exemplo 1**

```
<script language="javascript">
 <!--
 var nome;
 nome = window.prompt("Digite o nome:");
 for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
 { 
 window['v' +i] = "var " + i; 
 } 
 // recuperando as variaveis 
 alert(v1); // variavel 1 
 alert(v2); // variavel 2 
 alert(v3); // variavel 3 
 //-->
</script>
```

**Exemplo 2**

```
<script language="javascript">
 <!--
 //criando variável dinâmica
 var valor;
 valorTeste = window.prompt("Digite o nome:");
 for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 eval("nome" +i+ " = '"+valor+"';");

 //recuperando os valores dessas variáveis
 alert(window["nome" +i]);
 }
 //-->
</script>
```

**Exemplo 3**

> Agora, vamos criar variáveis dinâmicas usando o *objeto* `window` do javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
 <!--
 //criando algumas variáveis dinamicamente
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
 window["nome" + i] = i + 10;
 }

 //recuperando os valores dessas variáveis
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
 alert(window["nome" + i]);
 }
</script>
```

**Exemplo 4**

```
<script language="javascript">
 <!--
 //criando variável dinâmica
 var nome;
 nome = window.prompt("Digite o nome:");
 for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 alert(eval+"(var "+nome+i+" = '"+i+"';)");
 }
 //-->
</script>
```

> Estes exemplos são muito simples, embora pouco práticos.

Answer (score 0):

No Html faça o seguinte:

```
<input type="text" id="seuInput"  onkeyup="keyupFunction()">
```

No javascript:

```
function keyupFunction() {
   var valor_do_campo_aqui = document.getElementById("seuinput").value;
}
```

Comment: O autor da pergunta quer criar uma "_variavel dinâmica_". Acho que quer algo do tipo `window[input.value] = 'foo';`... convidei-o para o chat. Vamos ver se a pergunta fica mais clara.

Comment: @Sergio Valeu pela dica, não vi que você tinha postado um link eu ainda estava escrevendo.